# Styling - vertical-align image and text inside a tag inside td tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am recently coding a navigation dropdown menu.
I add `style="vertical-align: middle;"` everywhere.
The image and text still won't align middle vertically.
I need the table still there so I can add more `td`s.
I'm done trying, would someone kindly help me?

```html
<style>
a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(203, 227, 255, 0.625) !important;
}
</style>

<table align="center" class="exc">
<tr>
<td class="null" style="white-space:nowrap; vertial-align: middle; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 50px; border: 2px solid #87ceeb !important; background-color: rgba(224, 255, 255, 0.625);">
<a href="https://example.com" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration: none; color: #6699cc;">
<font size="6">&#160;
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/home-icon.png" width="48px" style="vertial-align: middle; width=100%; height:100%;" />
&#160;HOME&#160;&#160;&#160;</font>
</a>
</td>
<td class="null" style="white-space:nowrap; vertial-align: middle; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 50px; border: 2px solid #87ceeb !important; background-color: rgba(224, 255, 255, 0.625);">
<a href="https://example.com" style="display:inline-block; width=100%; height:100%; text-decoration: none; color: #6699cc;">
<font size="6">&#160;&#160;&#160;HOME&#160;&#160;&#160;</font>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **CSS Flexbox** inside of `<td>`. Make a new parent `<div class="holder"></div>` inside of `<td>` & wrap the image and text inside of it.

Like:

```
<div class="holder"> <!-- Flex Container -->
  <img src="your-img">
  YOUR TEXT
</div>
```

Have a look at the snippet below to understand it properly:

```css
a:hover {
    background-color: rgba(203, 227, 255, 0.625) !important;
}

.second-td:hover {
    background-color: rgba(203, 227, 255, 0.625) !important;
}

.holder {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  font-size: 25px;
}
```

```html
<table align="center" class="exc">
<tr>
<td class="null" style="white-space:nowrap; vertial-align: middle; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 50px; border: 2px solid #87ceeb !important; background-color: rgba(224, 255, 255, 0.625);">
<a href="https://example.com" style="display:inline-block; text-decoration: none; color: #6699cc;">
<div class="holder">&#160;
<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicloads/100-flat/128/home-icon.png" width="48px" style="vertial-align: middle; width=100%; height:100%;" />
&#160;HOME&#160;&#160;&#160;</div>
</a>
</td>
<td class="null second-td" style="white-space:nowrap; vertial-align: middle; overflow:hidden; border-radius: 50px; border: 2px solid #87ceeb !important; background-color: rgba(224, 255, 255, 0.625);">
<a class="hoder" href="https://example.com" style="width=100%; height:100%; text-decoration: none; color: #6699cc;">
<div class="holder">&#160;&#160;&#160;HOME&#160;&#160;&#160;</div>
</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your generous help and respond in a short time!

Comment: @ll55 Its my pleasure!

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height instead of vertial-align: middle. That should do the trick ;)